# Extending cographs with product operation

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-classes, cliquewidth

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the class of undirected graphs defined inductively as follows:

- A single vertex is in $\mathcal{C}$;
- If $G\in\mathcal{C}$ then its [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) $\overline{G}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$;
- If $G,H\in\mathcal{C}$ then their disjoint union $G\oplus H$ is in $\mathcal{C}$;
- If $G,H\in\mathcal{C}$ then their [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) $G\otimes H$ is in $\mathcal{C}$.

This class of graphs appears in linear logic: this is how coherent spaces are defined.

I would like to now if this class have been studied from the point of view of graph theory. Does it have a name? Does it admit other characterizations?

If we restrict the definition to the first three lines we get cographs. But when we add the product operation we can create the 4-nodes path $P_4$, clique-width is then $>2$. But is the clique-width bounded for the whole class?

Thank you in advance for your help.

**Update after daniello's answer**

It was not clear for me how to generate paths of arbitrary lengths. This can be done by induction as follows, where the induction hypothesis is:

"$\forall n$, there is a graph $G_n$ of $\mathcal{C}$ containing $P_n$ as an induced subgraph"

- The paths $P_2$ and $P_3$ are clearly in $\mathcal{C}$. Take $G_2$ and $G_3$ to be respectively $P_2$ and $P_3$.
- For $n\geq 4$, we define $G_n$ as the tensor product of $G_{n-1}$ (obtained by IH) with the graph $H_n$ whose set of vertices is $[1,n]$ and which contains an edge between every pair of vertices except between $n$ and $n-3$. The graph $H_n$ is clearly a cograph thus belongs to $\mathcal{C}$. It is not very hard to see that $G_{n-1}\otimes H_n$ contains $P_n$ as an induced subgraph.

Comment: Following your construction; i think for every graph G your class contains a graph H that contains G as an induced subgraph

Comment: That is right, interesting !

Answer (score 5):

A path has cliquewidth $3$, but the tensor product of two paths of length $n$ will contain a $\Omega(n) \times \Omega(n)$ size grid as an induced subgraph. And $n \times n$ grids are known to have cliquewidth $\Omega(n)$ (see “*The rank-width of the square grid*“ by Vít Jelínek)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: It was not clear for me why $\mathcal{C}$ contains paths of arbitrary lengths. I updated my post to make this clear.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that just having cliquewidth 3 does not imply a construction using your operations, thanks for the catch and save :)